# Djangostack deployment from google marketplace failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

We were trying to deploy the Bitnami Djangostack from the Google Marketplace. However, we seem to be getting permission error wduring deployment:

`Error: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Required 'compute.instances.create' permission for 'projects/xyz/zones/asia-east1-a/instances/django-1-vm'","reason":"forbidden"},{"domain":"global","message":"Required 'compute.disks.create' permission for 'projects/xyz/zones/asia-east1-a/disks/django-1-vm'","reason":"forbidden"},{"domain":"global","message":"Required 'compute.subnetworks.use' permission for 'projects/xyz/regions/asia-east1/subnetworks/default'","reason":"forbidden"},{"domain":"global","message":"Required 'compute.subnetworks.useExternalIp' permission for 'projects/xyz/regions/asia-east1/subnetworks/default'","reason":"forbidden"},{"domain":"global","message":"Required 'compute.instances.setMetadata' permission for 'projects/xyz/zones/asia-east1-a/instances/django-1-vm'","reason":"forbidden"},{"domain":"global","message":"Required 'compute.instances.setTags' permission for 'projects/xyz/zones/asia-east1-a/instances/django-1-vm'","reason":"forbidden"},{"domain":"global","message":"Required 'compute.instances.setServiceAccount' permission for 'projects/xyz/zones/asia-east1-a/instances/django-1-vm'","reason":"forbidden"}],"message":"Required 'compute.instances.create' permission for 'projects/xyz/zones/asia-east1-a/instances/django-1-vm'","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xyz/zones/asia-east1-a/instances","httpMethod":"POST","suggestion":"Consider granting permissions to number@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"}}`

We have already provided compute admin permissions as mentioned in the suggestions.

Comment: You don't have a proper permissions - either just to Compute Engine or the entire project - if you're not the owner or administrator in this project contact someone to grant you proper [permissions to be able to create GCE resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam).

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you're also using a service account that actually has proper permissions**. Your description may indicate that [you're authenticated with the wrong account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) that doesn't have permissions you need.

If that's not the case please check again your permissions - the error message clearly says which one are missing.

If your account doesn't have them - move to another point.

Since you can't grant permissions directly to the service account you need to use [roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam). In this case you can for example [create a new custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) with the permissions that are mentioned in the message. You can use either [Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles), [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/create) utility (or other methods) and [grant it](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/access-control#grant-roles) to the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) you're using.

Comment: @Mayank Does this solve your issue?